# Stretching Data Over Entire x-axis

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I plotted some data using Matplotlib and have this large whitespace gap on the end. Any ideas on how to get rid of it? (204 values are plotted)

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(osnow,'r-',label="Observations")
ax.plot(rsnow,'b-',label='MERRA')
plt.xlabel('Year')
plt.ylabel('Snow Depth (cm)')
plt.title('Station '+str(stations[c])+' Snow Depth Correlations')
ax.set_xticks(np.arange(0,205,12))
ax.set_xticklabels(['1979','1980','1981','1982','1983','1984','1985','1986','1987','1988',
                    '1989','1990','1991','1992','1993','1994','1995','1996'], fontsize = 'small')
ax.text(30.0,35.0,'R = '+str(corr[0])+'', ha='center', va='center')
plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: try with `ax.autoscale(True)` (instead of setting it to `False`)

Comment: @hitzg I should have taken that out. I get the same result for True and False.

Comment: try `ax.set_xlim((0,204))` .. .since your `x` values go up to 205 it is probably rounded up ...

Answer (score 1):

As @plonser said above,

```
ax.set_xlim(0,205)
```